# Showing same xaml format image inside multiple dataGrid cells by utilising IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a working solution to convert boolean value into a xaml-image wrapped inside `<Viewbox>` by using `<ContentControl>` as follows:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Recommended, Converter={StaticResource BoolImageConverter}}" Height="20"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But with the above solution the converted image is only shown in the first cell.

> How can I properly use `<ControlTemplate>` or `<Control>` in this
>   case?

[I have looked into this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681167/1069643) but I'm unable to reproduce a working solution with the `Converter`.

Example of the xaml-image

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Viewbox x:Key="Symbols.StarIcon">
        <Canvas Width="46" Height="44" >
           ...
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The Converter idea is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444817/1069643):

```
public class BoolToImage : IValueConverter
{
    public Viewbox TrueImage { get; set; }
    public Viewbox FalseImage { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
        {
            return null;
        }

        bool b = (bool)value;
        if (b)
        {
            return this.TrueImage;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.FalseImage;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewBox is a control with a key. And control can have only one visual parent. So the first cell monopolizes ViewBox, and others can't use it.

In your case it is better to use [CellTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. 
First, create custom DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class TrueFalseSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public DataTemplate TrueTemplate { get; set; }
   public DataTemplate FalseTemplate { get; set; }

   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (item == null) return null;

      var isSomething = ((CustomObjectType) item).CustomBoolProperty;
      return isSomething ? this.TrueTemplate
                         : FalseTemplate;
   }
}
```

Then use it in XAML. Add Selector in Resources somewhere:

```
 <local:TrueFalseSelector x:Key="trueFalseSelector">
      <local:TrueFalseSelector.TrueTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <!-- your true template here -->
          </DataTemplate>
      </local:TrueFalseSelector.TrueTemplate>
      <local:TrueFalseSelector.FalseTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <!-- your false template here -->
          </DataTemplate>
      </local:TrueFalseSelector.FalseTemplate>
 </local:TrueFalseSelector>
```

And voila:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource trueFalseSelector}" />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

EDIT: you can place DataTemplates in the same dictionary where your ViewBox is right now. Give them a key and just use like this:

```
<local:TrueFalseSelector x:Key="trueFalseSelector"
                         FalseTemplate="{StaticResource falseTemplate}"
                         TrueTemplate="{StaticResource trueTemplate">
```

Comment: Beginner questions: `((CustomObjectType) item)` lines `item` is `DataGrid.NewItemPlaceholder` and I'am unable to gain access to the boolean value (casting fails)? Additionally, how do I link the xml-image into the True template? btw thanks for the different approach idea !

Comment: @ajr, first question depends on how you bind your data. What's DataGrid's `ItemsSource`? Second: same as with your ViewBox, just place it inside DataTemplate and remove the key from it and it's children.

Comment: `ItemsSource` is `public ICollectionView`which loads its members from an Entity Framework entity and entity contains this boolean. Second question: Can I somehow reference this xaml-image by its key? I would rather not place the whole length of star image into the `view.xaml` resources.

Comment: @ajr, ah, I see. `NewItemPlaceholder` goes where new item should be. Just check for that type and return whatever value you want empty 'new row' to have.
As for the image, you don't have to put it into view. You can place whole selector or just the DataTemplates in whatever dictionary you want - see edit.

Comment: Ok! Regarding performance, which implementation is the less costing? Wrapping image inside ControlTemplate with using IValueConverter as suggested in my referenced posting(got it working) OR this solution OR the pure xaml way as suggested as other answer.

Comment: @ajr, that does not really matter, every approach is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Here is just another way you can do this (pure xaml):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource RecommendedStyle}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>  
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="RecommendedStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ViewBox x:Key="True"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Recommended}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ViewBox x:Key="False"/><!--This is image for false-->
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style>
```